# Dismiss view after reload collectionview

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, loading

I make an api call that gives me data and I put these data in a UICollectionView. First I make a loader view and then make a call and within completionHandler if I get data I first reload tableview and then dismiss the loader but the reverse is done dismiss loader first and then reload collection view

I tried to reload the UICollectionView but nothing happens.

```
HelpingMethods.showLoadingSpinner(count: count)
Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .methodDependent), headers: HelpingMethods.setUpHeaders()).log().responseJSON { (response) in

    switch response.result{
    case .failure( _):
        completionHandler(nil)
    case .success(let value):
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: .prettyPrinted)
            let offers = try JSONDecoder().decode(Offers.self, from: jsonData)
            HelpingMethods.dismissLoadingSpinner()
            completionHandler(offers)
        }catch let error {
            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I need to dismiss the loader after reloading the data.

Comment: I'm not seeing your call to reload here, but it sounds like a threading issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `HelpingMethods.dismissLoadingSpinner()` inside a dispatchqueue. Just like:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   HelpingMethods.dismissLoadingSpinner()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By this code you can solve the problem

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
       HelpingMethods.dismissLoadingSpinner()
    }
```